# Show/hide in a jQuery sticky menu (positioned in the middle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few problems with trying to make a sticky menu that shows/hides with a click button, which is why I'm thinking about getting rid off the whole show/hide option completely and probably rewriting it from scratch in the future.

I can identify 2 major problems:

1. How to make the show/hide button move along with the sticky menu but to make it in such a way so that it does not disappear with it when the hide button is clicked?
2. I tried quite a few options on how to animate the menu so that it toggles from right to left (and vice versa) but somehow each time there was something wrong (either with my code or the option I found). How do I do it properly? If I manage to animate it so that 90% of the div hides there will still be place for a hide/show button (and this will also solve problem #1).

Here is my code so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/ohkegetn/
(edit: correct jsfiddle link added)

HTML:

```
<div class="menuWrapper">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#" class="scroll"><li>One</li></a>
                    <a href="#" class="scroll"><li>Two</li></a>
                    <a href="#" class="scroll"><li>Three</li></a>
                    <a href="#" class="scroll"><li>Four</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>   
<div id="toggle">Show/Hide</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: black;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 180%;
    line-height: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}

a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menuWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 225px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    left: 0;
}

#toggle {
    top: 450px;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu {
    width: 150px;
    background: #0E586D;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
li {
    color: #e5e5e5;
    transition: 1s;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}

#menu ul a li:hover {
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0f6a84;
}
p {margin: 200px}
```

JS/jQuery:

```
// Toggle - show/hide
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
        $(".menuWrapper").fadeToggle("slide");
    });
});

// Sticky Menu

var sticky_offset;
$(document).ready(function() {

    var original_position_offset = $('#menu').position();
    sticky_offset = original_position_offset.top;
    $('#menu').css('position', 'relative');
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var sticky_height = $('#menu').outerHeight();
    var where_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var window_height = $(window).height();

    if((where_scroll) > sticky_offset) {
        $('#menu').css('position', 'fixed');
    }

    if((where_scroll) < (sticky_offset + sticky_height))  {
        $('#menu').css('position', 'relative');
    }  
});
```

Final notes:

The html/css code is probably a bit of a mess, sorry for that but its just a test version. They are not that relevant anyway. The jQuery part is.
Also I would like to stick to Javascript/jQuery without plugins if possible.

Big thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I solve your problem 
but this solution is as you think or not i donot know
[see this link](http://jsfiddle.net/rrvtechdiamond/pmv5gt6v/)

```
$(".scroll").mouseover(function() {
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    $("#toggle").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: pos.top + "px",
        left: (pos.left+width) + "px"
    })
});
```

Comment: This is some solution but it's not what I actually wanted. The show/hide changes its place depending on which link I'm targeting, its supposed to stick to one place (possibly slide to left along with the the menu). Also there is no animation and I need one. Thanks anyway.